# paypal integration

Tags: paypal

I am trying to integrate paypal contribution in civicrm in a way that whenever and transaction is completed in paypal for a business account it should show up on civicrm contribution page.

1. is this possible to do using IPNs for paypal standard?
2. I followed all the steps mentioned in https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/payment-processors/paypal-standard/ and trying to use sandbox paypal to test the transaction but even after completing paypal transaction to business account it is not showing up in civicrm contribution. How to debug this issue?
3. is there any way to verify if the IPN sent by paypal is correct or not?